# MySQL won't install on Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, installation

I'm trying to install MySQL for my Ubuntu VM 14.04 X86 64

I'm getting some error messages:

> 150424 11:40:15 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer
>   instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a
>   future release. Please use the full name instead. 150424 11:40:15
>   [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)  starting as
>   process 4724 ... start: Job failed to start invoke-rc.d: initscript
>   mysql, action "start" failed. dpkg: error processing package
>   mysql-server-5.5 (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation
>   script returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent
>   configuration of mysql-server: mysql-server depends on
>   mysql-server-5.5; however: Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured
>   yet. dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Setting up mysql-client
>   (5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ... Errors were encountered while
>   processing: mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg
>   returned an error code (1) W: Operation was interrupted before it
>   could finish

I have tried reinstalling and cleaning it up after and stuff...
It still gives the same error.
Anyone that have a clue?

Comment: SO is a programming site.  As this has more to do with the installation, I think you would have more luck looking at [sf] or [ask ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)

Comment: what did you use to install it? Seems pretty obvious there are dependency issues. Whatever those are, you need to solve them.

Comment: @PaulFrederiksen I used 'apt-get install mysql-server' do you know where to find an installation file instead?

Comment: @albin900 is everything up-to-date in terms of repo/dependencies?  *sudo apt-get update*  then retry installing mysql

Comment: @Musk No, latest version. Still same error :/

Comment: i see that this is relevent to the warning: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/setup-mysql-error-on-ubuntu-14-04 , but not the dependency error. :/ But they could be linked.

Comment: please read more carefully error backtrack: "Job failed to start invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed." .
Please, check system log files and mysql one for error reason, additionally try to start service manually